# Excel VBA Add-in reference not listed

Tags: vba, excel, excel-addins

I saved an Excel project as type "Excel Add-in" to the default directory under AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/AddIns.  The extension is .xlam.  Upon reopening Excel, this Add-in was listed under File-->Options-->Add-ins and I toggled the checkbox to select it.

In the VBA editor, this Add-in is displayed along with the other Add-ins listed under File-->Options-->Add-ins but none of the code can be called.  It is not listed in the available references and, when I use this window to browse for it, it is not detected in the AddIns directory -- despite clearly being there.

I notice that all of the other Add-in projects that were installed without problem are .xla file extensions.  We are using Excel 2010 but the problem is identical when I save the project as type "Excel 97-2003 Add-in" with an extension of .xla.

Advice is appreciated.

Comment: In the VBA Editor click on ThisWorkbook for your Add-In. In the Properties Window, make sure that IsAddin is set to True.

Comment: Are the functions in your addin marked as `Public`?

Comment: @IronMan: That did it.  Of course just saving the file as an Add-in wouldn't be enough. :/  If you want the SO cred, post this as the answer and I will accept it.  Thanks.

Comment: Also, click the check mark to show that you have accepted this answer and it resolved your issue. Thanks.

Comment: @nwhaught: Yes.  Thanks.  I don't have enough rep yet to upvote your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the VBA Editor click on ThisWorkbook for your Add-In. In the Properties Window, make sure that IsAddin is set to True. This also makes it easier to edit your addin. When you need to make changes to the add-in code, follow these steps:

1. Set the property to `False`
2. Make your edits
3. Change the property back to `True`
4. Click on the Save icon
5. Close Excel.
6. You will be prompted if you want to save the changes made to
   "addin.xlam", click yes.

And as @nwhaught suggested, make sure your functions are set to Public and not Private.